# com.apple.quarantine appearing in web server content

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio, zend-server

I have a development mac book pro, and I have zend server, zend studio. setup.

I recently ran into an issues where the server is return the string.

```html
   <body role="document" style="padding-bottom: 32px;">Mac OS X         2��ATTR��&amp;�&amp;com.apple.quarantineq/0006;58057668;Microsoft\x20Outlook;
```

I tried running this 
/usr/bin/xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine ~
 on all my sites, zend files,  but nothing is fixing.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem incase anyone runs into this in the future.

I had downloaded a zray plugin, from the web. and I installed it manually.

The process of downloading it and than installing it  produced the text on all output while zrat was enabled